# _template_styles' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

I'm getting a weird error; here is the data below.

I'll first start by telling you what I did and why.

I have a client with a hacked Joomla site. For safety's sake, I installed a new Joomla and all of the components and the template.

I then migrated the database over. Initially, I had issues with the PHP version being 7.4 and showing the extensions table doesn't exist. So, I migrated to a higher version of Joomla.

I now see this error.

```
Table '**********_dez*nqx_pyn5RTX*peu.cw1ji_template_styles' doesn't exist
```

At the bottom of the page I see:

```
Warning: session_write_close(): Failed to write session data using user defined save handler. (session.save_path: /opt/alt/php82/var/lib/php/session, handler: Joomla\Session\Handler\DatabaseHandler::write) in /home/cripplecreeksqua/public_html/dev/libraries/vendor/joomla/session/src/Storage/NativeStorage.php on line 114
```

The front end says:

```
_menu' doesn't exist



 mysqli_sql_exception

Table '********.cw1ji_session' doesn't exist
```

I have tried repairing the database.

Comment: In the configuration.php change the session handler from `public $session_handler = 'database';` to `public $session_handler = 'filesystem';`. That should remove the warning about sessions by not using the DB table which is probably as missing or corrupt as your other tables.

Comment: That fixed it.  Well it provided a new error which is not database related `Attempted to load class "Helper" from namespace "HelixUltimate\Framework\Platform".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?`.  Thank you!

Comment: If you mark your comment as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Argh, I still can't reach the back end because it says `Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by "/home/cripplecreeksqua/public_html/libraries/src/Application/WebApplication.php" at line 404.`